# Identifying an IC named T072

Tags: identification

I'm trying to identify an IC named T072. It's used in several places inside a Rega Brio-R audio amplifier and it seems to be in the audio path. I can see it in the audio input paths but also int the record output audio path. It may be Texas Instruments based on that I see a logo that resembles the TI logo. Am I perhaps looking at a version of the TL072 OP from TI?

Unfortunately I don't have a picture of the circuit right now but I will try to  fix one.

Comment: I 've seen a T072 in several Chinese sellers (e.g [this one](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-New-Original-TL072CPSR-T072-SOP8-LOW-NOISE-JFET-INPUT-OPERATIONAL-AMPLIFIERS/32239512885.html) ) and they all refer to a TL072 opamp, but I can't find any documentation for it and it is not mentioned in the TI datasheet for TL072.

Comment: The circuit in the link sure looks like the one on my PCB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Page 21 of the [TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl074.pdf). It shows "Device Marking" for each package for each opamp, because the full text you'd like won't fit on the smaller packages.

Specifically, the SO and TSSOP packages are labelled "T072" for the TL072.